# Why does my OS become very slow when/after launching VS Code unless launching with extensions disabled?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Today when I launched Visual Studio Code, my [Debian 9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_version_history#Debian_9_(Stretch)) (Stretch) became very slow.

But when I then started it using `code --disable-extensions` in the terminal, it worked normally.

How can I detect the extension causing the slow startup?

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_19#_running-extensions

Answer (score 11):

Please follow [this guide](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/wiki/Performance-Issues) for help tracking down which extension is causing performance issues.

To start, run `code --status` from the command line while Visual Studio Code is running. This will print out a list of all Visual Studio Code processes and their resource usage:

[image]

Once you track down the bad extension, please file an issue against them.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that probably one or a couple of your extensions are activating upon startup and taking a long time to activate. You can find out how long each extension is taking to activate by using the `Developer: Show Running Extensions` command in the command palette, which will show activation times for all enabled extensions, and whether the extension was activated during startup, or later after startup finished. If there are extensions that you don't typically use in all your workspaces that are slow to activate, I'd suggest you disable them globally and [enable them on a per-workspace basis](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-marketplace#_enable-an-extension).

I'd also check out https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Performance-Issues#slow-startup. There are instructions there for using `code --prof-startup` to gather profile files if you want to report an issue ticket, and [instructions on how to read startup timers](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Performance-Issues#read-the-startup-timers) by using the `Developer: Startup Performance` command in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette).

If your system is slowing down, then I'd also suggest to look at your system monitoring tool and check up on the memory consumption and CPU usage of VS-Code-related/owned processes. VS Code also has a builtin Process Explorer, which you can open with `Developer: Open Process Explorer` in the command palette, which also shows CPU usage and memory usage.