# how to improve the speed of visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

my visual studio is becoming slower with usage. I have only one extension installed and enabled.
Are there any steps which will enhance the performance of it.

I'm  working on react-redux with material ui project.

i have only one extension that is prettier.

Comment: Are u sure its vs? Create a new project and gauge performance,  it could be your existing project is bloated.

Comment: VScode is slow. It just is. I find I have to keep my files small. Some people will claim I should be keeping them small anyway but when it's just a hobby project it's frustrating to have to refactor my project because the text editor sucks. I like many of the features of VSCode but it's an incredibly slow editor (though I hear Atom is slower)

Comment: @jodesK yes on creating new project . but then i reinstelled it now it is working fine

Answer (score 3):

You should check out this [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47997042/when-launch-vscode-my-so-is-very-slow) from another post on stackoverflow.com.

You could also try opening the command palette(ctrl + shift + p on Win) and typing the command "Show Running Extensions" to see if you have any extensions that are maybe "hanging up" or extensions that you are not aware of.